# add rows on the selection of row in a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to add more rows on the did select method of table view.
I am showing data on the table view by  a web service and  when click on a row add more rows according to another web service. and when click another row hide first one all rows.

Actually i want to do this same as happened in Linked in iPhone app

Can you all help me..
Appreciate your ideas

thanks.

Comment: When you change the information, tell your table to `reloadData`.  It will ask you for the number of rows and you give it the new value.  Is there a problem with that?

Comment: I have to use another web service means on the did select method i need to add more rows and show data according to webservice

Comment: You said that already...so get the new data, call [yourTable reloadData], and give it the new information when it asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download apple source code from this link

```
[http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html][1]
```

Comment: Thanks, Its great, i will use it

Answer (score 2):

If you want insert a new cell with **insertRowsAtIndexPath** you have to update first the dataSource of the table. Moreover this method should be called between:

**[table beginUpdates];**

and

**[table endUpdates];**

From this:

Note the behavior of this method when it is called in an animation block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods. UITableView defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections. This happens regardless of ordering of the insertion and deletion method calls. This is unlike inserting or removing an item in a mutable array, where the operation can affect the array index used for the successive insertion or removal operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)AddButtonAction

{

[arry addObject:@"Tutorial "];//in your array add json data after parsing and than call this method..

[Table reloadData];

}

- (void)DeleteButtonAction

{

[arry removeLastObject];

[Table reloadData];

}
```

[For tutorial or sample code visit this reference site..](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DeleteandaddrowfromTableView.html)

Hope,this will help you